# SSIS SQL job scheduling conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I've been given the task to schedule 2 SSIS packages (by the way I'm a Jr.Data Analyst and starting to get my feet wet with SSIS). Here is the scenario:
I have a package that needs to be scheduled to run weekly at 1pm every Friday (this sends out files to an ouside vendor). Will call this the weekly package.
I have another package for the same vendor that needs to be scheduled to run the first friday of every month. Will call this the monthly package.
So I have scheduled the weekly package to run every Friday BUT I need the weekly package not to run the Friday that the monthly package will run. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Have you figured out how to get the first Friday of each month yet?

Answer (score 1):

Add an 'Execute SQL' task that runs:

```
IF (DATEPART(day,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 AND DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE())%7 = 4) RAISERROR('Skip job on first Friday of month',16,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it easy and schedule four jobs. Weeks 1, 2 & 3 would be the weekly package and the 4th would be the monthly package. SQL server agent makes it easy to do this.